# Multiprocessing, writing to file, and deadlock on large loops

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a very weird problem with the code below. when `numrows = 10` the Process loops completes itself and proceeds to finish. If the growing list becomes larger it goes into a deadlock. Why is this and how can I solve this?

```
import multiprocessing, time, sys

# ----------------- Calculation Engine -------------------
def feed(queue, parlist):
    for par in parlist:
        queue.put(par)

def calc(queueIn, queueOut):
    while True:
        try:
            par = queueIn.get(block = False)
            print "Project ID: %s started. " % par
            res = doCalculation(par)
            queueOut.put(res)

        except:
            break

def write(queue, fname):
    print 'Started to write to file'
    fhandle = open(fname, "w")
    while True:
        try:
            res = queue.get(block = False)
            for m in res:
                print >>fhandle, m
        except:
            break
    fhandle.close()
    print 'Complete writing to the file'


def doCalculation(project_ID):
    numrows = 100
    toFileRowList = []

    for i in range(numrows):
        toFileRowList.append([project_ID]*100)
        print "%s %s" % (multiprocessing.current_process().name, i)

    return toFileRowList


def main():
    parlist     = [276, 266]

    nthreads    = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    workerQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    writerQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    feedProc = multiprocessing.Process(target = feed , args = (workerQueue, parlist))
    calcProc = [multiprocessing.Process(target = calc , args = (workerQueue, writerQueue)) for i in range(nthreads)]
    writProc = multiprocessing.Process(target = write, args = (writerQueue, 'somefile.csv'))

    feedProc.start()
    feedProc.join ()

    for p in calcProc:
        p.start()
    for p in calcProc:
        p.join()

    writProc.start()
    writProc.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the Queue buffer getting filled, so you need to read from the queue before you can put additional stuff in it.
For example, in your `feed` thread you have:

```
queue.put(par)
```

If you keep putting much stuff without reading this will cause it to block untill the buffer is freed, but the problem is that you only free the buffer in your `calc` thread, which in turn doesn't get started before you join your blocking `feed` thread.

So, in order for your `feed` thread to finish, the buffer should be freed, but the buffer won't be freed before the thread finishes :)

Try organizing your queues access more.

Comment: That is true. It seems the buffer is the problem. Have to find a way to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The feedProc and the writeProc are not actually running in parallel with the rest of your program. When you have

```
proc.start()
proc.join ()
```

you start the process and then, on the `join()` you immediatly wait for it to finish. In this case there's no gain in multiprocessing, only overhead. Try to start ALL processes at once before you join them. This will also have the effect that your queues get emptied regularyl and you won't deadlock.

Comment: Unfortunately, brining `writProc.start()` above the joins did not help.

Comment: Start all the processes first before joining any of them
    `feedProc.start()
    for p in calcProc:
        p.start()    
    writProc.start()
    feedProc.join ()
    for p in calcProc:
        p.join()
    writProc.join()`